# How to convert cartesian limits of integration to polar?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a double integral over $y$ and $z$ where $z \in [-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}, \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}]$ and $y \in [-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}, \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}]$.

I defined

$$
y = r\sin \theta \\
z = r\cos \theta
$$

It is intuitive to me visually that the limits of integration in polar are $r \in [0, \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}]$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, but I am struggling to show this mathematically.

I know that
$$
r\cos\theta \in \left[-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}, \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2} \right] \\
r\sin\theta \in \left[-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}, \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} \right] \\
$$

But where do I go from here mathematically to show the limits on $r$ and $\theta$?

This problem arose from deriving the marginal pdf of $X$ for points uniformly distributed within a sphere of radius $R$. The joint distribution is $f_{XYZ}(x,y,z) = \frac{3}{4\pi R^2}$, and I am integrating this over $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Do you have a double integral or a triple integral? Note that $$y\in \Big[-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2},\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}\Big] \iff x^2+2y^2\leq R^2$$ so the region in the $(x,y)-$ plane over which you're integrating is the interior of the ellipse $x^2+2y^2 =R^2$

Comment: @MatthewPilling It is just a double integral. $x$ here can be treated as a constant. Note this is from a problem where I was trying to derive a marginal PDF for $X$ by integrating the joint PDF (which in my case is just the inverse of the volume of a sphere) of $X,Y,Z$ over $Y$ and $Z$. I didn't include this because I didn't think it'd be relevant.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Why is it $x^2 + 2y^2 \leq R^2$ instead of $x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2$?

Comment: Note $$y\in \Big[-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2},\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}\Big]$$ is equivalent to saying $$|y| \leq \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$$ Now square both sides and add $y^2$. Also, it's usually preferred on this site to provide as much context as possible.

Comment: @MatthewPilling sorry, I have a huge typo. The bounds I gave for $y$ are actually for $z$. I have those 2 swapped. I'm going to edit the OP.

Comment: @MatthewPilling But applying your idea, I get
$$
z^2 \leq R^2 - x^2 - y^2 \\
\therefore r^2 \leq R^2 - x^2
$$

Comment: Your joint density $f$ is defined over a ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered about the origin, correct? If so, notice that the *projection* of the intersection of the plane $X=x$ with the ball $X^2+Y^2+Z^2\leq R^2$ onto the $yz-$ plane where $-R\leq x\leq R$ fixed is the disc $$Y^2+Z^2 \leq R^2-x^2$$ which can be expressed in polar form as $$0\leq r \leq \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$$ $$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling Right, that's how I visualized it, but when I wrote it down mathematically, I was struggling with the limits conversion, although it's intuitive graphically what it should be. How do you actually show that the bounds on $\theta$ should be $0$ and $2\pi$?

Comment: The graph of $Y^2+Z^2 \leq R^2 -x^2$ in the $YZ-$plane with $x\in [-R,R]$ fixed describes an entire filled in disc of radius $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ centered about the origin, not just some portion of it.

Comment: If I asked you to evaluate $\iint_RfdA$ where $R$ is the region given by $x^2+y^2\leq 9$, you would describe this region as $0\leq r\leq 3$, $0\leq \theta \leq2\pi$ since $x^2+y^2 \leq 9$ describes the entire filled in disc of radius $3$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yeah I understand. What I was initially trying to show is I wanted to take the formulas $y = r\cos\theta$ and $z = r\sin \theta$ and then plug in their respective limits, and from this, observe that $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, but I think that gets messy.